# Python / Selenium - Not able to extract text from text box

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following python code to extract text from a text box

```
def check():
    with open("LP_input.txt") as f:
         for line in f:
             url = line.strip()
             driver.get(url)
             driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
             time.sleep(10)
             PC = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='wwctrl_landingPageDataForm_attributeMap_STRUCTURE_DATA_REQUIRED']")
             for x in PC:
                 print(x)
```

My HTML (web page where I am extracting text)

```
<div id="wwctrl_landingPageDataForm_attributeMap_STRUCTURE_DATA_REQUIRED" class="wwctrl">
<input id="landingPageDataForm_attributeMap_STRUCTURE_DATA_REQUIRED" class="text medium" name="attributeMap.STRUCTURE_DATA_REQUIRED" maxlength="1000" value="TRUE" style="" type="text"
```

But am getting this error;

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9f5789eaeb8dbd5cc005dc63e3d4f9f2", element="0.6714808439487934-1")>
```

Actually the textbox will contain either TRUE or FALSE.. I want to extract this for thousands of pages.

Comment: that is not the error, that is selenium element object, solution to your issue is to get text from that element do `PC.text()` instead of running a for loop

Comment: @Stack Tried using .text() still issue not solved.. now program closes without showing error.. but output not received.. I guess xpath is the culprit..

Comment: just add an extra input at last, the script is working correctly, the terminal just closes quickly at the end. So by just adding input it will work

Comment: What do u mean by adding an extra input.. pls specify

Comment: pls check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `id` as `landingPageDataForm_attributeMap_STRUCTURE_DATA_REQUIRED` and `name` as `attributeMap.STRUCTURE_DATA_REQUIRED` it seems both the attributes are dynamically generated. Hence we need to construct a dynamic `xpath` or `css` to get all the `WebElements` first. We need to store the `WebElements` in a `List` then traverse the `List` of `WebElements` to retrive the value of `value` field which is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` as follows:

```
PC = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'landingPageDataForm')][@class='text medium']")
for x in PC:
    text = x.getText();
    print(text)
```

Comment: Tried using the xpath given, It is extracting other text box since given xpath is wrong..

Comment: but its not working.. I have tried several different combination of xpaths including yours.. Its not throwing any error.. but not getting desired output too

Answer (score 0):

I have added the extra input, change your code to :

```
def check():
    with open("LP_input.txt") as f:
         for line in f:
            url = line.strip()
            driver.get(url)
            driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            time.sleep(10)
            PC = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='wwctrl_landingPageDataForm_attributeMap_STRUCTURE_DATA_REQUIRED']")
            for x in PC:
                print(x.text())

            #Extra Input, to prevent the script from closing.
            input("Press any key to exit!!")
```